# Dynamic programming efficient network

Tags: dynamic-programming, directed-graphs

Hello I have a dynamic programming  related question. How can I compute the shortest path in hops from starting vertex u to ending vertex v, with the constrain that the vertices and edges will have an equal or higher predefined value. For example the highest rate of data in a network,

i.e. the vertices A,B,C,D and E with values unlimited,6,2,5 and unlimited respectively, also the edges A->B, A->C, B->D, C->D and D->E with values 4,3,5,8 and 10 respectively. In this case the most efficient path from A to E would be A->B, B->D, D->E.

Could someone provide some pseudo-code or any thoughts, thank you in advance.

My main concern because is not like an implementation issue. So what I am thinking: Find the longest path in DAG with Dijkstra's, and some tweaks (multiply the weights of the edges with -1, finding shortest path and then multiplying again with -1 for longest), however I should fit in the values of the vertices to.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem statement. Can you make the first paragraph in your question more formal? Also Dijkstra's Algorithm wouldn't directly work for negative weights, you should use Bellman-Ford algorithm.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChavali I tried to clarify the first part of my question by providing an example.  Also I don't necessarily have negative weights in the graph, I wanted to do the conversion so I could compute the longest path. But not sure about that since I need the path with least hops (least routers), but with the most weighted ( most bandwidth)

Comment: Make your objective function and constraints clearer. From what I could grasp, you want the path with the least number of hops as your first priority(3 hops in your example) and then if there is a tie, you break it by using the condition that the sum of weights of all the vertices and edges on that path should be maximum. Is this correct?

Comment: @ChaitanyaChavali Yes, exactly, only correction first to prioritize by path weight (since the data loss must be avoided) and if there is a tie choose the one with least hopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a modified version of Dijkstra's Algorithm with 3 modifications.

First of all you change all the weights from w to (W-w) where W is some large value. Since your case is an acyclic graph, I don't think you need Bellman-Ford algorithm.

The update step in Dijkstra's looks somewhat like this for a vertex v which is adjacent to u

```
if dst[v] > dst[u] + weight[(u,v)]
    dst[v] = dst[u] + weight[(u,v)]
```

You should modify this to include the vertex weights.

```
if dst[v] > dst[u] + weight[(u,v)] + weight[u]
    dst[v] = dst[u] + weight[(u,v)] + weight[u]
```

Also in Dijkstra, you store the predecessor in the shortest path for each vertex. In your case, you should store a set of predecessors because you are looking for multiple shortest paths.

At the end you can consider all the shortest paths(longest originally) and select the one with least hops.

Comment: Just a little clarification. Since I need to make sure that the "buffer" capacity of each node (router) and edge(link) is not less than the predefined value shouldn't the if statement be like:                                                                                       `if ((dst[v] > dst[u] + weight[(u,v)] + weight[u]) && (predValue <= weight[(u,v)] && predValue <= weight[(u,v)]))  
                           dst[v] = dst[u] + weight[(u,v)] + weight[u]`